# Install Xcode on OS X 10.8.4

Tags: applications, xcode

I'm a Windows user and don't know anything about Macs. Now I have to create a web app for iPhone (it just opens a website inside an app).

I tried installing Xcode 5, but it's not compatible with OS X 10.8.4. I think I have to download Xcode 4, but I can't find it anywhere?

How do I install Xcode on OS X 10.8.4?

<sup>(I can't update this OS X because the Mac is not mine.)</sup>

Comment: I would say you don't really need Xcode to develop a web app since you can put the code onto any web server and they do not go through the app store at all in terms of needing a developer account, certificate or any help from Apple. Are you assuming you need Xcode or is there a requirement you haven't detailed in the question that mandates your use of Xcode?

Comment: dude your sentences are way too long, and yes I'm just assuming I need Xcode, and what do you mean with : put the code on to any webserver?

Comment: You used web app to indicate a native app with UiWebView or other framework but most people will assume "Web App" to mean coding for something to run in [Safari/WebKit](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/navigation/index.html#section=Resource+Types&topic=Coding+How-Tos) and not an app store app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Old Xcode versions can be downloaded from [developer.apple.com](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action), free registration is required for this. To install (and distribute) your own applications, you'll need to register as an iOS developer. This costs $99/year but can easily be done later.

Having said that, you may not even need to develop an app for what you have in mind. In Mobile Safari you can save any web site/URL as an application icon on your home screen. When tapped on, this will open the web site as an application.

Comment: thanks! so can create an app that's not in the istore, but you can download it with a link, and it's just a web app, and not pay 100/year? I don't get it

Comment: No, every user has to create the icon him/herself, but you can put installation instructions on the website.

Comment: I installed a latest macos in a virtualbox, installed latest xcode, bought license, created a webview app, but it in the istore, (so much work :s android is so easy) but they did not approve the app, next time I'll use phonegap

Answer (score 0):

The Below links you get free download for Xcode 4.6.3

[Xcode 4.6.3 download](http://www.tomsguide.com/us/download/xCode-4,0301-46197.html)

Note:

You may also get via torrents